# Eshell prompt regex

Tags: eshell, regular-expressions

I'm trying to get my two-lined eshell prompt working with eshell. It gets displayed alright, and it's also non-readable. But when I call something external, the cursor doesn't jump "down" to the new prompt line, only on internal things. And then hitting return again, it copies the line down - but it copies the full line, not just the actual command.
My prompt is:

```
  (defun shk-eshell-prompt ()
(let ()
  (concat
   (with-face user-login-name :foreground "blue")
   "@"
   (with-face "localhost" :foreground "green")
   (with-face ":" :foreground "green")
   (with-face (concat (eshell/pwd) " ") :foreground "green")
   (with-face (format-time-string "(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M) " (current-time)) :foreground "#888")
   (with-face
    (or (ignore-errors (format "(%s)" (vc-responsible-backend default-directory))) ""))
   (with-face "\n")
   (if (= (user-uid) 0)
       (with-face "#" :foreground "red")
     "$")
   " ")))
```

The regexp is the following, made with `regexp-builder`:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9-_~/]+ [())(0-9a-zA-Z: -]+
. "
```

(Quotes for clarification that a whitespace is at the end). Now what's wrong with this regexp? Does the eshell have some sort of a special regex syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it seems like I only have to provide a regexp for the second line! This makes my solution

```
". "
```